# Making Unreal Engine 4 Objects Like Cubes Swimable

Tags: physics, game-physics, unreal-engine4

I'm developing a Unreal Engine 4 Survival Game and I have so far allocated to areas for lakes and have entered cubes with water like textures and I want to make it so that you can enter the cube and go into a swimming position. I also need it to have a different color texture when you move into places so that 2 meters away it will be dark and closer light and when you move it changes. I dont mind if we can do one thing at a time. If you guys can help me I would be extremly grateful! Hope you can help!

Answer (score 0):

Set the cube up as a trigger and collide with pawns. When the Cube blueprint has an "OnActorBeginOverlap" cast it to pawn blueprint then call a function on it to tell it to go to swim mode.

https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Engine/Blueprints/UserGuide/Events/

Answer (score 0):

You need to first add a collision component in the blueprint viewport of the cube, then place events for triggering material effects, which simulate underwater scene, or you can fairly simply create a post-processing volume like that one on YouTube: w[]ww.youtube.com/watch?v=fLtSfG8f6NM ( Delete the "[]"s )

For super flamboyant but hard effect, check this one out: w[]ww.youtube.com/watch?v=8jbK00s2tKg ( Delete the "[]"s )

The most important part is to implement underwater floating movements. Create another character blueprint that has a floating pawn component in it. After that, add an event to spawn this floating pawn as a runtime object in level blueprint using "SpawnActorByClass" blueprint( tip: using C++ is much more convenient for manipulating runtime objects ) and possess it( https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Gameplay/HowTo/PossessPawns/Blueprints/ ). You can modify some floating pawn settings to get better effects.

Plus: Feel free to ask me any questions. In addition, YouTube is a fantastic place for learning UE4. ExpressVPN works if you can't visit YouTube.